# non-Abelian subgroup of order 6 in $S_5$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations, symmetric-groups

First off, yes, this is a homework question. However, I've been trying everything and I just feel like I must be missing something obvious.

In $S_5$, the only way to get a subgroup of order 6 would be to do a disjoint cycle like $(abc)(de)$, so we can have an order of $lcm(3,2)=6$. However, any subgroup in $S_5$ with distinct elements for $(abc)(de)$ just ends up with the set of $e, (abc)(de), (acb), (de), (abc), (acb)(de)$, and it seems to always be Abelian.

What am I doing wrong? Anything at all would be appreciated.

Comment: What about $S_3$?  A subgroup generated by a single element will be cyclic, hence Abelian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think about the set of all permutations that act only on the first $3$ elements -- namely the subgroup $S_3 \leq S_5$. But $|S_3|=6$ and it is nonabelian, so it's exactly what you're looking for!

You do not need an element of order $6$ -- that would be required to get a cyclic group of order $6$, but that is Abelian anyways, so we don't want that.

Comment: Ah, because cyclic groups are always Abelian! No wonder I was only getting Abelian groups

Comment: RMS, you're exactly right, since, in any group, elements commute with their powers. If all elements are just powers of a single generator, then everything commutes!

Answer (score 1):

You've correctly noted that the only *elements* of order $6$ in $S_5$ are of cycle type $(2,3)$. However, it's not the case that a group of order $6$ needs to contain an element of order $6$. For example, $S_3$ is a non-abelian group of order $6$, and none of its elements have order $6$. Can you find a copy of $S_3$ inside $S_5$?

Comment: I was completely tunnel-visioning and only looking at the elements in $S_5$, so I'm glad you let me know about $S_3$, but I'm having a hard time understanding what you mean by "Can you find a copy of $S_3$ inside $S_5$?" Do you mean something like $(123)(4)(5)$? I'm almost sure this isn't what you mean since that has an order of 3, though.

Comment: By "a copy of $S_3$ inside $S_5$", I mean a subgroup of $S_5$ which is isomorphic to $S_3$. You just listed one element, but we're not looking an *element* of $S_5$, we're looking for a *subgroup*. Does that help?

Comment: Somewhat, I think. As another answer said, $S_3 \leq S_5$, so just listing out $S_3$ seems to be enough?

Comment: Yes, depending on your definitions of $S_3$ and $S_5$! If you've defined your symmetric groups so that $S_3 \subseteq S_5$ then this is exactly right.